# Quickest way to count occurrence of values in multi-index pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, count

I have two multi-index dataframe with many levels and columns. I'm looking for the quickest way to iterate over the dataframe and count, for each row, how many cells are above a specific value in each dataframe and then find the intersection of the rows of the two dataframe that scored at least one count.

Right now I'm cycling through the dataframe with a combination of for loop and groupby but it's taking me too much time to find the right answer (my real dataframe comprise thousands of levels and hundreds of columns) so I need to find a different way to do this.

So for example:

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[0,1],[0,1,2]],names= 
['index_1','index_2'])
 col = ['column_1', 'column_2']


values_list_a=[[1,2],[2,2],[2,1],[-8,1],[2,0],[2,1]]
DFA = pd.DataFrame(values_list_a, idx, col)

DFA:
                   columns_1 columns2
index_1 index_2
  0       0            1        2
          1            2        2
          2            2        1
  1       0            -8       1
          1            2        0
          2            2        1

values_list_b=[[2,2],[0,1],[2,2],[2,2],[1,0],[1,2]]
DFB = pd.DataFrame(values_list_b, idx, col)

DFB:
                   columns_1 columns2
index_1 index_2
  0       0            2        2
          1            0        1
          2            2        2
  1       0            2        2
          1            1        0
          2            1        2
```

What I expect is:

Step 1 counting occurrence:

```
DFA:
                   columns_1 columns2 counts
index_1 index_2
  0       0            1        2       1
          1            2        2       2
          2            2        1       1
  1       0            -8       1       0
          1            2        0       1
          2            2        1       1

DFB:
                   columns_1 columns2 counts
index_1 index_2
  0       0            2        2        2
          1            0        1        0
          2            2        2        2
  1       0            2        2        2
          1            1        0        0
          2            1        2        1
```

Step 2: The intersection of the 2 dataframe with counts >0 should create a new dataframe like this (where the row of both dataframe that score at least one count in the same indices are recorded and a new index_0 level is added). the index_0 = 0 should refer to the DFA and index_0=1 to DFB:

```
DFC:
                            columns_1 columns2 counts
  index_0 index_1 index_2
     0       0       0            1        2       1
                     2            2        1       1
             1       2            2        1       1

     1       0       0            2        2       2
                     2            2        2       2
             1       2            1        2       1
```

Comment: Can you provide the code to create your DataFrames? Handling Multi-indices is tough

Comment: *I'm looking for the quickest way to iterate over the dataframe and count* so your `specific value` here is `1`?

Comment: yes any cell with value >=2 (or above 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### `pd.concat` then `magic`

```
def f(d, thresh=1):
    c = d.gt(thresh).sum(1)
    mask = c.gt(0).groupby(level=[1, 2]).transform('all')
    return d.assign(counts=c)[mask]

pd.concat({'bar': DFA, 'foo': DFB}, names=['index_0']).pipe(f)

                         column_1  column_2  counts
index_0 index_1 index_2                            
bar     0       0               1         2       1
                2               2         1       1
        1       2               2         1       1
foo     0       0               2         2       2
                2               2         2       2
        1       2               1         2       1
```

---

#### With Comments

```
def f(d, thresh=1):
    # count how many are greater than a threshold `thresh` per row
    c = d.gt(thresh).sum(1)

    # find where `counts` are > `0` for both dataframes
    # conveniently dropped into one dataframe so we can do
    # this nifty `groupby` trick
    mask = c.gt(0).groupby(level=[1, 2]).transform('all')
    #                                    \-------/
    #                         This is key to broadcasting over 
    #                         original index rather than collapsing
    #                         over the index levels we grouped by

    #     create a new column named `counts`
    #         /------------\ 
    return d.assign(counts=c)[mask]
    #                         \--/
    #                    filter with boolean mask

# Use concat to smash two dataframes together into one
pd.concat({'bar': DFA, 'foo': DFB}, names=['index_0']).pipe(f)
```

Comment: looks like it's working, can you explain what is going on?

Comment: @GiovanniMariaStrampelli see if that helps.

Comment: what if I want to assign a a value at the index_0. Instead being the default [0,1] make it ['bar','foo'] ? can it also work index-wise (instead column-wise). What I mean is right now we are looking for each row if there are values >=2. what if I want to se if in each column there are values >=2 and do the same exercise?

Comment: @GiovanniMariaStrampelli updated post... that should do it

Answer (score 0):

```
df.groupby(['index_0','index_1', 'index2'])
```

now , you want to use having equivalent of sql, which is

```
df.filter(lambda x: len(x.columns_1) > 2)
df.count()
```

this is a concept , i didnt understand what do you want to filter,
note that x is a group, so you need to operate on it (len, set, values) etc

Comment: In the first step I want to find for each given row  how many cells are equal or above a given value (in the example is 2). So if we take for example just the first row of the first DF the answer will be 1 because only the columns 2 of the index=(0,0) is >=2.

If we take the index =(0,1) the answer is 2 and so on as shown in the example

Comment: df.filter(lambda x: min(x.columns) >= 2)
this will force the minimum value of a column in a group to be 2 , otherwise its filterd

Answer (score 0):

Use filter, .any() and pd.merge()

Recreate the dataframe:

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[0,1],[0,1,2]], names=['one', 'two'])
columns = ['columns_1', 'columns_2']

DFA = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(-1,3, size=[6,2]), idx, columns)
DFB = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(-1,3, size=[6,2]), idx, columns)

print(DFA)

             columns_1  columns_2
one two                      
0   0           -1          2
    1            2         -1
    2           -1          0
1   0            1          2
    1            0          0
    2           -1         -1



print(DFB)

             columns_1  columns_2
one two                      
0   0            2         -1
    1            1          2
    2            2          1
1   0            0          0
    1           -1          2
    2            1         -1
```

Filter the dataframes for values > 1 in this instance.

```
DFA = DFA.loc[(DFA>1).any(bool_only=True, axis=1),:]
DFB = DFB.loc[(DFB>1).any(bool_only=True, axis=1),:]

print(DFA)

             columns_1  columns_2
one two                      
0   0           -1          2
    1            2         -1
1   0            1          2

print(DFB)

        columns_1  columns_2
one two                      
0   0            2         -1
    1            1          2
    2            2          1
1   1           -1          2
```

Merge the two together. Using out join gets you close. Not sure about jumping the index out, but the first level 0 [0,1] is DFA.

```
         columns_1_x  columns_2_x  columns_1_y  columns_2_y
one two                                                    
0   0           -1.0          2.0          2.0         -1.0
    1            2.0         -1.0          1.0          2.0
1   0            1.0          2.0          NaN          NaN
0   2            NaN          NaN          2.0          1.0
1   1            NaN          NaN         -1.0          2.0
```

Comment: So this is a very good idea. What if I have a third column, say column_3 and I want the row that are >=2 in at least 2 columns? The second point is not what I need, I thin I have to concatenate the DFA and DFB taking only the one that score

Comment: I changed it to outer join but the index is still stacked at level 0

Comment: For three or more columns, replace the .any() filter with this (DFA>1).sum(axis=1)>=2   (forget the astype, not needed.)